# Преобразование из string (char) в int

Tags: c#, массивы, типы-данных, синтаксис, конвертация

```
int num = 123456;
string numString = num.ToString();
int[] arrayNum = new int[6];
arrayNum[0] = int.Parse(numString[0]);
```

Пытаюсь конвертировать char в int с помощью int.Parse() но выдает ошибку
Ошибку: Suppression State Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan'

P.S. Если написать `Convert.ToInt32()` Выдает вообще 49.

Comment: `int.Parse(numString[0].ToString());` или так `arrayNum[0] = numString[0] - '0';`. А вообще `int.Parse` не умеет `char`, он умеет только `string`

Comment: Можно вообще в 1 строку `int[] arrayNum = num.ToString().Select(x => x - '0').ToArray();`

Comment: спс всё работает